# No hits for nested analyzed field in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We want to search our nested field "texts" in multiple languages. However, when applying additional fields with different analyzers, we never get any hits.

Our configuration works for non-nested fields (such as "title" in the example below), so it seems to be related to the nesting somehow.

Mapping configuration:

```
{
"properties": {
"title": {
  "type": "string",
  "fields": {
    "en": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "english"
    }
  }
},
"texts": {
  "type": "nested",
  "value": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
      "en": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Test code:

```
TransportClient testClient = new TransportClient()
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostname, port));

String test_index = "test_index";
IndicesExistsResponse indicesExistsResponse = testClient.admin().indices().exists(new IndicesExistsRequest(test_index))
    .actionGet();

if (indicesExistsResponse.isExists()) {
  testClient.admin().indices().prepareDelete(test_index).execute().actionGet();
}
testClient.admin().indices().prepareCreate(test_index).execute().actionGet();

String source = Streams.copyToStringFromClasspath("/index.json");
testClient.admin().indices()
    .preparePutMapping(test_index)
    .setType(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSource(source).execute().actionGet();

Article article = new Article();
article.title = "Winter is coming";

Text text = new Text();
text.value = "The nicest summer shoes";
text.textId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

article.texts = Collections.singletonList(text);

testClient.index(new IndexRequest(test_index, ARTICLE_TYPE, article.articleId)
    .source(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(article))
    .refresh(true)).actionGet();


SearchHits rawTitleSearchHits = testClient.prepareSearch(test_index)
    .setTypes(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(queryStringQuery("title:winter"))
    .execute().get().getHits();

SearchHits enTitleSearchHits = testClient.prepareSearch(test_index)
    .setTypes(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(queryStringQuery("title.en:winter"))
    .execute().get().getHits();

SearchHits rawTextSearchHits = testClient.prepareSearch(test_index)
    .setTypes(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(nestedQuery("texts", queryStringQuery("value:summer")))
    .execute().get().getHits();

SearchHits enTextSearchHits = testClient.prepareSearch(test_index)
    .setTypes(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(nestedQuery("texts", queryStringQuery("value.en:summer")))
    .execute().get().getHits();

SearchHits enTextSearchMatchHits = client.prepareSearch(test_index)
    .setTypes(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(nestedQuery("texts", matchQuery("value.en", "summer")))
    .execute().get().getHits();


assertThat(rawTextSearchHits.getTotalHits(), is(1L));
assertThat(rawTitleSearchHits.getTotalHits(), is(1L));
assertThat(enTitleSearchHits.getTotalHits(), is(1L));

// Fails. Why??
assertThat(enTextSearchHits.getTotalHits(), is(1L));

// Also fails. Why??
assertThat(enTextSearchMatchHits.getTotalHits(), is(1L));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping for the `nested` field is missing the `properties` structure:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "en": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    },
    "texts": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {               <--- this structure is missing
        "value": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "en": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After changing your mapping, you'll need to reindex your data.

**UPDATE**

Finally, in your query you need to use the full field path, i.e. `texts.value.en` instead of just `value.en`:

```
SearchHits enTextSearchHits = testClient.prepareSearch(test_index)
    .setTypes(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(nestedQuery("texts", queryStringQuery("texts.value.en:summer")))
    .execute().get().getHits();

SearchHits enTextSearchMatchHits = client.prepareSearch(test_index)
    .setTypes(ARTICLE_TYPE)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(nestedQuery("texts", matchQuery("texts.value.en", "summer")))
    .execute().get().getHits();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still doesn't work though. Same result with 0 hits on the last assertion.

Comment: Did you wipe your index clean and reindex your data?

Comment: Yes. As you can see in the test code I delete and re-create the index on every test run.

Comment: Yes, my bad I overlooked that. Actually, the issue seems to come from trying to use nested fields in a `query_string`. As far as I know, [this is still unsupported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322). If you can use nested match queries, you should be fine, though.

Comment: I cannot get match query to work either. Modified the original question.

Comment: I think you need to specify the full field path, i.e. `matchQuery("texts.value.en", "summer")`

Comment: Awesome. That solved it! Both queryString and match works now! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88487/discussion-between-mattias-holmqvist-and-val).